# Segmentation fault: 11 received in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

Hi im new to socket programming im trying to receive a username from my client. I currently have the following method written in my server file:

```
/* Reads a message from the server socket. */
char *recv_msg(int sockfd)
{

    char *msg;
    /* All messages are 9 bytes. */
    memset(msg, 0, 8);
    int n = read(sockfd, msg, 8);

    if (n < 1 || n >9) /* Not what we were expecting. Server got killed or the other client disconnected. */
        error("ERROR reading message from server socket.");

    return msg;
}
```

i am calling my function like this:

```
/* Authentication Process */
        write(cli_sockfd[num_conn], "USN", sizeof(int));
        char *username;
        username = recv_msg(cli_sockfd[num_conn]);
        printf("[DEBUG] Client username is %s.\n", username);
```

I know the client successfully receives the "USN" message but i am getting a 'Segmentation fault: 11' i believe on the `username = recv_msg(cli_sockfd[num_conn]);` could someone please explain and help me out as to why?

Comment: Somewhere between `char *msg;` and `memset(msg, 0, 8);`, that `msg` variable had better be set to point to at *least* eight bytes. Post a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following line in the function `char *recv_msg(int sockfd)`

```
 memset(msg, 0, 8);
```

The function prototype of `memset` is this:

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

The memset function copies the value of c (converted to an unsigned char) into
each of the first n characters of **the object pointed to by s**.

In your case, `msg` is a `char` pointer which has not been allocated any memory.

So you must do the following:

```
 char *msg;
 msg = malloc(8);
 memset(msg, 0, 8);
```

And don't forget to free the memory later on.